# How can i combine two columns to filter on using between?

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

i have two columns in my data called year and month. I would only like to extract data where date is greater > 201802 and less than 202103.

```
select 


* 

from table 

where year+month between 201802 and 202103..
```

is what i would like. both my columns are ints.. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic:

```
where year * 100 + month between 201802 and 202103
```

Or, you can use tuples (but not with `between`):

```
where (year, month) >= (2018, 02) and
      (year, month) <= (2021, 03)
```